# Is light spectra different for all living bodies?

Tags: visible-light, frequency, biophysics, vision

As we know that honey bees can see lots of different colours, is it possible that the light spectra is different for them?

My main question is that is light spectra different for all living organisms? Due to different light frequencies?

Comment: The difference in the light frequencies bees are sensitive to is different from ours because both animals occupy different ecological niches and therefore have evolved for different specialization. Bees need to understand light from flowers well, because flowers give them their food. We need to understand light from fast food neon lit logos well, because they lead us to our food :)

Comment: Can we extract a bee lens and experiment upon it , combination of uv lights can be made used as a weapon too :0

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about physics

Comment: If you ask about *how* different animals detect different colors from one another, this may be a question better suited to this site. The cone cells of different animals have different pigments with sensitivities to different wavelengths. How these different pigments give rise to electrical, neural signals in response to incident light is definitely a physics question. I suspect there may not be too many people here knowledgeable about this last point; biology SE may also be worth a try.

Comment: It is a physics question according to me as well...

Comment: This is clearly a physics question. I'm nominating it for reopening.

Comment: Even different individuals in the same species see light differently ... think about colorblind people. Most people see 3 dimensions of color, because we have 3 different cone receptors in our eyes. One can make a correspondence of these three dimensions to hue, muddiness, and brightness, and that's the way our brain interprets it. I would guess animals with 3 types of color receptors see colors more or less the way humans do.

Comment: But a swallowtail butterfly has [15 different types](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2016/03/butterfly-has-extreme-color-vision) of color receptors. Maybe they have this many to better distinguish the colors of flowers (although honeybees do fine with three, even though they can see UV light). It's anybody's guess how they see color, but it certainly won't be the way humans see it.

Comment: Is it possible that some organisms can see some other colour other than black in space?